# Support multiple urls for same WCF service (as web url rewrite)

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service hosted by IIS.
It is documented to programmers as service end point;
 `https://api.company.com/services/soap1`

but client must define endpoint 
 `https://api.company.com/services/soap1/`

Question; How can I support them also without pain? Is there any way like url re-write for wcf services requests add last trail automaticaly?

note: service work with mtom encoding SOAP messages.

Comment: Simply configure multiple end point.
Google about multiple configuration of same WCF service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF allows you to configure multiple endpoints for the same service.

```
<services>
 <servicename ="MultipleEndpoints.Service1" behaviorConfiguration ="Mg">
    <endpointname="firstBinding"
      address ="https://api.company.com/services/soap1"
      binding ="basicHttpBinding"
      contract ="MultipleEndpoints.IService1" />
     <endpointname="secondBinding"
       address ="https://api.company.com/services/soap1/"
       binding ="basicHttpBinding"
      contract ="MultipleEndpoints.IService1"/>
    <endpointcontract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
 </service>
 </services>
```

For an example see: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/configuring-multiple-end-points-for-wcf-service/